# Get name of control calling method

Tags: c#, forms

My form has several numeric up down controls.  All of these controls, when changed, call the same method:

```
    private void SetColors(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

How do I determine which control called the method?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's what the `sender` parameter is for.

If you know the time, you can cast it appropriately:

```
NumericUpDownControl control = (NumericUpDownControl) sender;
```

If it could be any of several types, you can use `as` and a null test, or `is` followed by a cast.

Of course, you only need to cast to the type which contains the members you need - so you could potentially just cast to `Control`, for example.

EDIT: Suppose you just want the name, and you know that the sender will always be a control of some kind. You can use:

```
private void SetColors(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Control control = (Control) sender;
    String name = control.Name;
    // Use the name here
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Jon.  I am just learning C#, so could you include a sample line of code to illustrate what you mean?  It would be ideal to obtain the name of the calling control.

Comment: @Jimmy: Okay, I've given an example here. If you could give more details about what you want to happen, we may be able to help you more.

Comment: When I try this in the KeyDown event of a dynamic textbox, i get nothing as name! Why?

Comment: @SamarthAgarwal: Well did you assign a value to the `Name` property? If not, what would you expect it to give?

Answer (score 2):

The control on that the event occured is stored in the variable `sender`. You just need to cast it back to its original type.